# Cascade merge one-to-one relationships in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-one

Given below an example of a one-to-one relationship.

OrderTable (inverse side as suggested by `mappedBy`) :

```
public class OrderTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Long orderId;

    @Column(name = "order_status", length = 45)
    private String orderStatus;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orderTable", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Billing billing;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Constructors + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

Owning side  (having a foreign key) :

```
public class Billing implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "billing_id", nullable = false)
    private Long billingId;

    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 45)
    private String firstName;

    @JoinColumn(name = "billing_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private OrderTable orderTable;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Constructors + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

Trying to cascade merge as follows.

```
Billing billing = entityManager.find(Billing.class, 1L);
billing.setFirstName("XXX");

OrderTable orderTable = entityManager.find(OrderTable.class, 8L);
orderTable.setOrderStatus("New");
orderTable.setBilling(billing);
billing.setOrderTable(orderTable);
entityManager.merge(orderTable);
```

Here, `OrderTable` is updated as it should. `Billing` on the other hand, is not intuitive, since there is a primary key which is also a foreign key in turn.

It appears that `OrderTable` in `Billing` should be replaced (updated) by a new one whose `orderId` is `8`, since `CascadeType` on the inverse side is set to `ALL`. It however, remains unchanged. Only the `order_status` column in the `order_table` table is updated (`orderTable.setOrderStatus("New");`) (but not its `billing_id` which is the foreign key in the underlying database table).

In case, the following line,

```
OrderTable orderTable = entityManager.find(OrderTable.class, 8L);
```

is replaced by

```
OrderTable orderTable = new OrderTable();
```

a new row in the `order_table` database table is created (leaving the corresponding existing row as it is) but corresponding `billing_id` in the `billing` database table remains intact (only the remaining fields are updated, if they are to be updated).

Is it somehow possible to replace a new `OrderTable` with an older one even though updating a primary key field does not look intuitive?

Purposely, `CascadeType` in one-to-one relationships on both the sides (inverse and owning) does not make sense (except for `CascadeType.REMOVE` and `CascadeType.PERSIST` only on the inverse side). Doesn't it?

<sub>Currently using EclipseLink 2.6.0</sub>

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  You've set the relationship as insertable = false, updatable = false, so you can't make changes to it.  JPA does not allow changing primary key values as they are the entity's identity and uniquely define the entity.  You will need to remove the old and create a new entity with the same values but a new pk.

Comment: Setting `insertable` and `updatable` to false on the owning side of the relationship is compulsory because the same field needs to be mapped twice across the entity once to denote the primary key and again to denote the `@OneToOne` relationship (the foreign key).

Comment: If both Entities share the same Primary Key, then you need to have `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on the `@OneToOne` association(s).

Comment: PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is a JPA 1.0 artifact, but it basically just makes the mapping read-only as you are already doing.  I believe you were refering to MapsID or even putting the ID on the relationship mapping, which are 2.0 additions.  Regardless, JPA does not allow changing ID values in any version.  You must remove then recreate your entity as a different instance..  Otherwise, use some other value populated with a sequence for the ID that you do not need to change when you want to map the billing to a different OrderTable.

Comment: @Chris : It is not a real requirement. It is merely an attempt to understand one-to-one relationships at length :). (BTW, there was a typographical mistake in my previous comment. Therefore, I deleted it)